# Как передать код подтверждения при авторизации через aiogram, чтобы пользователь мог ввести его через чат бота, а не в терминал командной строки?

Tags: python, telegram, авторизация, telethon, aiogram-2.x

Скину кусок кода.

```
@dp.message_handler(state=add_account.ApiHash)
async def process_api_hash(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['api_hash'] = message.text

    phone_number = data['phone_number']
    api_id = data['api_id']
    api_hash = data['api_hash']


    client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash)
    await client.start()

    await message.answer("Введите код подтверждения:")
    await add_account.ConfirmationCode.set()
```

Пользователь поочередно указывает номер телефона, api_id и api_hash от аккаунта. На моменте, где мы должны авторизоваться подставив эти данные и создать сессию, необходимо подтвердить вход кодом, который приходит на аккаунт.
Суть проблемы: telethon хочет, чтобы код был введен непосредственно в терминал, но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог ввести код в чат боту и он передался в сессию, дабы мы вошли в аккаунт.
Ломаю голову, не могу сделать. Помогите пожалуйста.